# Date type input for Android Studio?

Tags: android, date, android-studio, datetime, datepicker

Is there a date-picker input type for Android Studio that is similar to the drop-down date-type input picker for HTML?

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_input_date_get

The Android DatePicker is too big, takes up a lot of screen space, and doesn't provide the year input.

I'm planning to use a date-picker to receive user input's birthdate for example.  Or is there a better way of getting date-based inputs?

Comment: Yes there is a date picker!

Comment: Have you done a [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+datepicker+year+site:stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: Like I said, all I found is the really big, clunky datepicker that doesn't have a year input (only month and day) with the big calendar.  I was just wondering if there was a drop-down type where it also has a year input.

Comment: YourWorstNightmare but it is dialogue it automatically cancel after select date and android mobile users have not big enough space to see html kind picker .and its hard for user to select .so its easy to use default datepicker .

Comment: i have example of it refer this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm). that shows you can select year from it.